# 30 w discharge and half the windows uptime

Tags: hp, battery

I'm new to linux and I installed ubuntu 11.10 x64. I got a HP Envy 14 laptop (i7 second gen) and my batterytime is half the uptime I get in windows 7. Now I got 2hours and it discharges in 30w. In windows I get about 4-5 hours uptime.

I have done some guides so I only use the integrated graphicscard. I ran powertop and pasted it here below, if someone can get something out of it.. seems strange with a lot of posts on 100%. I dont know what to look for :/

PowerTOP 1.97     Overview   Idle stats   Frequency stats   Device stats   Tunables

The battery reports a discharge rate of 29.9 W

```
          Usage     Device name
          6.3%        CPU use
         20.0%        Display backlight
         20.0%        Display backlight
         20.0%        Display backlight
          0.0%        Audio codec hwC0D0: IDT
        601.7 pkts/s  Network interface: wlan0 (iwlagn)
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Cont
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Control
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Con
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
        100.0%        PCI Device: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 8
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Control
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controll
        100.0%        PCI Device: ATI Technologies Inc NI Whistler [AMD Radeon HD 6600M Series]
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6230
        100.0%        PCI Device: Atheros Communications AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet
```

Exit |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In powertop, go to the last tab and try enabling some tweaks to lower power consumtion, also, installing Jupiter might help, (I reccomend searching it at webupd.org since they have a PPA with newer versions that in the Ubuntu Repos), also, search for propietary drivers, as they may lower heat and power consumption on your laptop. Go to System Settings and try to set it up to a more power-saving setting.

Good luck!